# How to determine whether a file or folder is hidden in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa

How to determine whether a file or folder is hidden in Mac OS X, like we have `GetFileAttributes` in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Is the file hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140235/is-the-file-hidden)

(The matter is complicated because there are multiple factors that can cause a file to be "hidden" - the Launch Services approach described in the linked post ought to cover all of them.)